# Custom JSON Generic Type Serialization not working

Tags: json, serialization, .net-core, system.text.json, .net-5

I am using the new .NET serialization classes from System.Text.Json to deserialize a JSON response from a restful endpoint. The structure of the response is:

```
public class RemoteCallResultDto
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class RemoteCallResultDto<T> : RemoteCallResultDto
{
    public T Payload { get; set; }
}
```

The generic type is what i want to deserialize. The Payload could be a primitive or a class. So i created a custom converter as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1).

My converter is as follows:

```
public class RemoteCallResultDtoTConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert.IsGenericType &&
                typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(RemoteCallResultDto<>);
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Type valueType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        JsonConverter converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(RemoteCallResultDtoConverterInner<>).MakeGenericType(
                new Type[] { valueType }),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            binder: null,
            args: new object[] { options },
            culture: null);

        return converter;
    }

    private class RemoteCallResultDtoConverterInner<TPayloadType> : JsonConverter<RemoteCallResultDto<TPayloadType>>
    {
        private readonly JsonConverter<TPayloadType> _valueConverter;

        public RemoteCallResultDtoConverterInner(JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // For performance, use the existing converter if available.
            _valueConverter = (JsonConverter<TPayloadType>)options
                .GetConverter(typeof(TPayloadType));
        }

        public override RemoteCallResultDto<TPayloadType> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (_valueConverter != null)
                return new RemoteCallResultDto<TPayloadType> { Payload = _valueConverter.Read(ref reader, typeToConvert, options) };
            else
                throw new JsonException();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, RemoteCallResultDto<TPayloadType> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (_valueConverter != null)
                _valueConverter.Write(writer, value.Payload, options);
            else
                throw new JsonException();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the **_valueConverter** in the ***RemoteCallResultDtoConverterInner*** constructor is always null.
This is how i attempt to do the deserialization:

```
 var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        serializerOptions.Converters.Add(new RemoteCallResultDtoTConverter());

        RemoteCallResultDto<K> res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RemoteCallResultDto<K>>(response, serializerOptions);
```

Where the response is valid JSON of the form:

```
{"payload":{"email":"arlvinm@yahoo.com","firstName":"Arlvin","lastName":"Moyo","organization":"Aquants","permissions":["User management - View","Lookup data - View"]},"succeeded":true,"message":null}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You don't need a converter, only the right NamingPolicy. 
Use `serializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;` instead of your converter

Comment: 1) Your code doesn't compile because the type `K` is not found.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/QPguzA.  2) Why do you need a converter at all?  This converter looks like it's trying to handle polymorphism, but the type to which to deserialize, `RemoteCallResultDto<K>`, is fully defined.  What is the converter trying to do?

Comment: 3) As shown in the [Sample factory pattern converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter), `_valueConverter` might be null, in which case you should call `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TPayloadType>(ref reader, options)`

Comment: @Kalten, thanks. Your comment was actually the answer, i.e. setting the PropertyNamingPolicy. You were right, i don't need a converter. I've up-voted your comment. I suppose because it's just a comment i couldn't mark it as the answer, which it is. To user dbc, I wasn't getting results so i thought perhaps i needed a converter. Am still learning all this. If you can point me to an article that explains when one needs a converter i'd appreciate it.